# How to tell Rubocop only look at specific directories?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I want to include only specific directories, and ignore everything else.

This ignores everything

```
AllCops:
  Include:
    - 'something/**/*.rb'

  Exclude:
    - '**/*'
```

And this inspects everything

```
AllCops:
  Include:
    - 'something/**/*.rb'
```

Answer (score 3):

It [*appears*](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/issues/4247) that the latest version (~0.56+) of Rubocop will only include files (or patterns) specified in `Include`, if you define `Include`.

This would mean that if all you do is:

```
AllCops:
  Include:
    - 'something/**/*.rb'
```

Then *only* `something/**/*.rb` will be inspected. It *overwrites* the default files instead of appending to it.

I think this is new functionality because that's what it's doing for us now and that's not how it was before. Very deceiving for a minor version release.

Answer (score 0):

Regex seems to work, but very ugly

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - !ruby/regexp /^((?!(something|some\/other\/dir)).)*$/
```

Comment: I agree this is very hard to read. Is there an alternative syntax or behaviour you'd like? Care to open an issue in the RuboCop GitHub repo? :-)